# How to record a short video after I take picture?

Tags: android, image, video, record, capture

I made app that takes picture when button is pressed and another app that records 3 second video when you open app.I want to start recording video immediately after I press Capture button.When I try to connect capturing and recording in one app It always crash. 
How to connect this two codes and make it capture video after capturing image ?

this is code for taking and saving picture when button is pressed

```
    public class PreviewActivity extends Activity implements 
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.ShutterCallback, Camera.PictureCallback {

            Camera mCamera;
            SurfaceView mPreview;

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

                mPreview = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
                mPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);
                mPreview.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

                mCamera = Camera.open();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
                mCamera.release();
                Log.d("CAMERA", "Destroy");
            }

            public void onCancelClick(View v) {    // this is from Cancel Button
                finish();
            }

            public void onSnapClick(View v) {      // this is from Capture button
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onShutter() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                //Here, we chose internal storage
                File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

                if (pictureFile == null) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    //write the file
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                    fos.write(data);
                    fos.close();

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
                camera.startPreview();
            }
            private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
                //make a new file directory inside the "sdcard" folder
                File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/", "Taken Picture");

                //if this "JCGCamera folder does not exist
                if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                    //if you cannot make this folder return
                    if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                //take the current timeStamp
                String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
                File mediaFile;
                //and make a media file:
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

                return mediaFile;
            }
            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                Camera.Parameters parameters=mCamera.getParameters();

                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                {
                    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                    parameters.set("rotation",90);

                    //parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
                    Log.i("alengenije","portrait");
                }
                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                {
                    parameters.set("rotation", 0);

                    //parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
                    Log.i("alengenije", "landscape");

                }
                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                try {
                    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Log.i("PREVIEW","surfaceDestroyed");
            }
        }
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#A000">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:onClick="onCancelClick"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Snap Photo"
            android:onClick="onSnapClick"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is code for recording video for 3 seconds:

```
public class VideoCapture extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    public Context context;
    private Camera camera;
    public static String videoPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath() +"/YOUR_VIDEO.mp4";

    public VideoCapture(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public VideoCapture(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public VideoCapture(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void init() {
        try {
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                    if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                        Log.i("alengenije", "video END");
                        recorder.stop();

                    }
                }
            });
            holder = getHolder();
            holder.addCallback(this);
            holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            camera = getCameraInstance();

            camera.unlock();
            recorder.setCamera(camera);
            recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
            recorder.setMaxDuration(3000);
            recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
            recorder.setOutputFile(videoPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder mHolder) {
        try {
            recorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopCapturingVideo() {
        try {
            recorder.stop();
            camera.lock();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(5)
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        if (recorder != null) {
            stopCapturingVideo();
            recorder.release();
            camera.lock();
            camera.release();
            recorder = null;
        }
    }

    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for us to try and guess the error from. What exactly is the error?

Comment: I don't know how to connect this two codes, where to put what, when I copy part from video recording and put it in PreviewActivity error is there, I just don't know what to put where. Should I define recorder in onCreate or when button is presses, where should I set camera output,videoSource,maxDuration....

Comment: So you want us to write your middleware?

Comment: I want someone to say if it is possible to do that (take picture and record short video) and if it is then how can I do that with code that i posted or is there maybe another way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Can you start recording for 4  seconds & then take thumbnail from 1st second & rest is your video. This way you don't have to start camera twice.

Comment: I start camera once and take picture and I want to record video after that with same camera.

Comment: Yeh you are right. I tell the same. Just change the way you are capturing photo & recording video. An application using camera twice sometimes gives problem. That's why follow my instructions. This way you don't have to start camera twice & you will get photo as well as video. Also try to add something new since this feature is available in any camera. User will think that you took picture first & then recorded the video, but actually you just taking video & then getting thumbnail from that video. Sometimes we are doing something & thinking in same way, but here you are adding new features to

Comment: Your idea, just take video , show two or more thumbnails & let user decide which thumbnail he wants

Comment: How is that avalible to every camera ?

Comment: No no no.  Suppose you took video of 3 seconds. Then you can get thumbnails from your video. Just Google how to get a thumbnails from video in Java. [Yt link]( https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=34ZFib3kGGM) & [post from stackexchange] ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30208850/get-thumbnail-from-video-in-java)